# Why are only the first 2 outputs correct in my binary to decimal converter programm?

Tags: c, binary, decimal

I have to program a converter which takes the strings from `numbers[]` and outputs them as decimals.

I am looping through size and index to then add up the current index to the power of its position and then sum it all up. Like: 101 = 1^2 + 0^1 + 1^0

So I am currently stuck with this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <math.h> // Kompilieren mit -lm : gcc -Wall -std=c11 dateiname.c -lm

int main() {
    char* numbers[] = {
        "01001001",
        "00101010",
        "010100111001",
        "011111110100101010010111",
        "0001010110011010101111101111010101110110",
        "01011100110000001101"};
    
    // Add here..

int strlen(char *str){
int len=0;
for(;str[len]!='\0';len++){}
return len;
}

int sum = 0;
int length = sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(numbers[0]);

for( int i = 0; i < length; i++ ){
    
     int size = strlen(numbers[i]);
     
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
     
        if(numbers[i][j] == '1'){ 
            sum += 1 * pow(2,j-1);
        }else{
            sum += 0 * pow(2,j-1);
        }
    }
       printf("%s to the base of 2 \nequals %d  to the base of 10 \n\n",numbers[i], sum); 
       sum = 0;
       
    }
            
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the first two loops is correct which is 01001001 = 73 and 00101010 = 42. But, as soon the length get bigger, my output is completely wrong; e.g. 010100111001 = 1253 instead of 1337 and 011111110100101010010111 = 7645567 instead of 8342167.

Comment: You count `j` starting from the left, but if you use `2**j`, `j` must be counted from the right. Your first two numbers _happen_ to be right, because they are nearly symmetric. The offset of −1 to "fix" that maskes the error.

Comment: Don't use `pow` to get integer powers of 2: use shifting. Also note that the fifth string has too many bits to convert to a 32-bit `int`. Also "binary to decimal conversion" is untrue, it is converting a digit string to binary. The binary to decimal conversion is done by `printf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code. First and foremost, as pointed out in the comments, you are processing your binary digits from left-to-right, whereas you *should* be doing that right-to-left.

Second, declaring a function inside another one (as you have done for your `strlen`) is not Standard C (though some compilers may allow it). If you really can't use the standard `strlen` function (provided in `<string.h>`), then move your definition to outside (and before) the body of `main`.

Third, you shouldn't be using the `pow` function (which takes and returns `double` values) for integer arithmetic. Just use a running `int` variable and multiply that by two each time the inner `for` loop runs.

Fourth, your `"0001010110011010101111101111010101110110"` value will overflow the `int` type on most machines (assuming that is 32 bits), so try using `long long int` (most likely 64 bits) where necessary.

Finally, there's no point in adding `0 * x` to anything, whatever `x` is, so you can do away with the `else` block.

Here's a working version (using the standard `strlen`):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> // For "strlen" - we don't need math.h if we don't use "pow".

int main(void) // For strict compliance, you should add the "void" argument list
{
    char* numbers[] = {
        "01001001",
        "00101010",
        "010100111001",
        "011111110100101010010111",
        "0001010110011010101111101111010101110110",
        "01011100110000001101" };

    long long int sum = 0; // So we can use more than 32 bits!
    size_t length = sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(numbers[0]);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        int size = (int)strlen(numbers[i]); // strlen gives a "size_t" type
        long long int p = 1;
        for (int j = size-1; j >= 0; j--) { // Start at the END of the string and work backwards!
            if (numbers[i][j] == '1') {
                sum += p;
            }
            // No point in adding zero times anything!
            p *= 2; // Times by two each time through the loop
        }
        printf("%s to the base of 2 \nequals %lld  to the base of 10 \n\n", numbers[i], sum);
        sum = 0;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Really, thank you so much! I am really new to c and this is my 4th assignment. It really helped how u broke down the "mistakes".

Comment: @0___________: And yet you have posted an answer, where you use the result of `strchr` without testing it for `NULL`. I doubt that will make it "correct for any data".

Comment: @MOehm right! corrected. I do not argue if someone has constructive remarks. Before another remark - it is up to the caller to pass valid pointers (same as the Standard library functions)

Comment: @AdrianMole cast does not prevent overflow.

Comment: @AdrianMole it does not matter at all if it is calculated compile or run time. Assigning the value which larger than INT_MAX is implementation-defined

Comment: @AdrianMole instead of correcting it, you argue that incorrect code is good.  Simply make it correct and I will remove all of my comments.

Comment: @0___________ Changing the `size` variable from a signed `int` to a `size_t` would require significant changes to the code - notably to the inner `for` loop. IMHO, that would make the code *poorer*, not better.

Comment: @AdrianMole that is the life. When code is bad from the beginning it has to be corrected. The argument that it will require some work is not very good and does not give a good example. Now OP thinks that using incorrect types is 100% correct

Comment: @0___________ OK - I've accepted the use of `size_t` for the `length` variable and outer loop index, and I've removed the 'unnecessary' `LL` suffix. However, I maintain that using a signed `int` for `size` and the inner loop index is the best code option. No string will be longer than `INT_MAX` in any working version of this code.

Comment: @AdrianMole here you have an example of how it should be done correctly. https://godbolt.org/z/o3r7M8Mce

Comment: @0___________ That's a completely different answer. You are welcome to not like my answer. I do like it. I have made some improvements based on your feedback but, it seems, you are now looking to just argue for argument's sake.

Comment: @AdrianMole if you like incorrect code ..... Added the correct one to my answer. EOD

Answer (score 0):

```
sizeof(); // it will give you the size of datatype (in bytes), not the length of a string.
```

You have to use string function instead.

```
length = strlen(numbers[0]);
```

Comment: But `sizeof` is only used to get the size of the test array (6) here. When dealing with the strings, the program uses `strlen`.

Comment: What is the purpose of: int length = sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(numbers[0]);

Comment: @OwaisYosuf It's a common idiom to get the length of an array.

Comment: int length = sizeof(numbers); // Length of an array.

Comment: That last comment is not true. `sizeof` will tell you how many bytes a variable occupies in memory, which is not the same as the length of an array.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is quite bad, complicated and uses `pow`. You do not need to know the length of the string.

It can be done much easier:

```
unsigned long long bstrtoint(const char *str)
{
    unsigned long long result = 0;

    while(*str)
    {
        result *= 2;
        result += *str++ == '1';
    }
    return result;
}
```

or for any base (lower than number of digits)

```
//bad digits considered as zeroes
static const char digits[] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ";
unsigned long long strtoint(const char *str, unsigned base)
{
    unsigned long long result = 0;
    char *ppos;

    while(*str)
    {
        result *= base;
        result += (ppos = strchr(digits, toupper(*str++))) ? (ppos - digits < base) ? ppos - digits : 0 : 0;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Examples:

```
    printf("%llu\n", bstrtoint("1111000011110000"));
    printf("%llu\n", strtoint("0001010110011010101111101111010101110110", 2));
    printf("%llu\n", strtoint("1dr45Xvy4", 36)); // base 36 number
```

https://godbolt.org/z/bsG5rfTsb

If you want to use your program layout and do it correctly:

```
int main(void) // For strict compliance, you should add the "void" argument list
{
    char* numbers[] = {
        "01001001",
        "00101010",
        "010100111001",
        "011111110100101010010111",
        "0001010110011010101111101111010101110110",
        "01011100110000001101" };

    unsigned long long sum = 0;
    size_t length = sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(numbers[0]);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    {
        size_t size = strlen(numbers[i]); // strlen gives a "size_t" type
        sum = 0;
        for (size_t j = 0; j < size; j++) 
        { 
            sum *= 2;
            if (numbers[i][j] == '1') 
            {
                sum += 1;
            }
        }
        printf("%s to the base of 2 \nequals %llu  to the base of 10 \n\n", numbers[i], sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but you do not have to integrate your string twice - `strlen` is not needed at all

```
int main(void) // For strict compliance, you should add the "void" argument list
{
    char* numbers[] = {
        "01001001",
        "00101010",
        "010100111001",
        "011111110100101010010111",
        "0001010110011010101111101111010101110110",
        "01011100110000001101" };

    unsigned long long sum = 0;
    size_t length = sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(numbers[0]);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    {
        sum = 0;
        for (size_t j = 0; numbers[i][j] != 0; j++) 
        { 
            sum *= 2;
            if (numbers[i][j] == '1') 
            {
                sum += 1;
            }
        }
        printf("%s to the base of 2 \nequals %llu  to the base of 10 \n\n", numbers[i], sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```